# How to cast a HashMap as a subclass in scala?

Tags: scala, types, casting

I've created the following class:

```
class Foo[T] extends collection.mutable.HashMap[T, Int] {...}
```

(The class has some methods, but to reproduce this problem it doesn't need any.)

When I clone an instance of this class and try to use it as another instance of `Foo`, I get the following type error:

```
scala> val f = new Foo[String]
f: Foo[String] = Map()

scala> val anotherF: Foo[String] = f.clone
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
found   : scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Int]
required: Foo[String]
```

How do I cast the result of `f.clone` as an instance of `Foo[String]` ?

**Update** A commenter pointed out that I could override the `clone` method on `HashMap`.  No objections to doing so, but it seems like I should be able to do so without reimplementing the actual cloning process.

Comment: Since the method `clone` is defined in HashMap and it yields an instance of HashMap you have to override it in your implementation of Foo i guess.

Comment: Re: overriding `clone` -- good point, I could re-implement it from scratch.  But if I want to override it with a method that calls HashMap's clone method, I end up with the same problem again.

Comment: Your class `Foo` could have additonal members or methods. The `clone` of HashMap can not help you here, because you need a new instance of `Foo`. And even if `Foo` has no additional members or methods, then an instance of HashMap should be acceptable.

Comment: My advice is to not take this route.  `map` and `filter` also won't return the correct values.  Either you should do all the work necessary to make `Foo` a full-fledged member of the collections hierarchy (with `CanBuldFrom` and all the rest), or you should use implicit conversions to add the methods you need.

Comment: Rex -- thanks!  Got it working with that approach, will write it up.  (I'm getting used to this sanctioned form of monkey-patching.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment from [Rex Kerr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247533/rex-kerr), the approach presented in the question is just wrong.

Instead, the scala-idiomatic approach is to use implicit definitions to add the `increment` method to HashMap objects:

```
type Counter[T] = collection.mutable.HashMap[T, Int]

class WrappedHash[T](val h: collection.mutable.HashMap[T, Int]) {
  def increment(key: T) = {
    val currentKeyCount: Int = h.getOrElse(key, 0)
    h ++= Map(key -> (currentKeyCount + 1))
  }
}

implicit def wrapHash[T](h: collection.mutable.HashMap[T, Int]) = new WrappedHash[T](h)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `HashMap` class returns `HashMap` objects, whether it is extended or not. If you want to change the return value, you have to extend `MapLike` as well.